# How to lock distros so they can only be used on 1 URL?

Tags: theming, distributions

I plan on making distributions for dating sites and stuff like that.

Maybe sell them as functional themes.

How do I lock the distribution and theme so the client can only use it on 1 URL?

I have seen this done with many website and templates, how can I do this with Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 possible approaches (there might be others):

- Include "something" that requires an API key, whereas 1 such key can be used on 1 URL only.
- Offer a "hosted" version only, which uses your distribution. That way you don't have to ... "*distribute*" the *distribution*.

PS: Drupal is GPL, so before creating something that is based on Drupal, make sure you do understand the legal aspects of GPL ...